# Filtering dates with return boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, filter

There are some codes that I wrote for filtering dates.
Here, **I tried to make a filter with return boolean**, but this code will work only for one object of the 'item' while **I need to filter this whole object in order to show to the site only working schedules at the present time**. *There is ask for optimizing that code I wrote.*

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
item = {
           "work_schedule": {
                "schedule": {
                    "MONDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "TUESDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "WEDNESDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "THURSDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "FRIDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    }
                }
            },
          "work_schedule": {
                "schedule": {
                    "MONDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "TUESDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "WEDNESDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "THURSDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "FRIDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "SATURDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    },
                    "SUNDAY": {
                        "begin": "10:00",
                        "finish": "22:00"
                    }
                }
            },
             "work_schedule": {
                "schedule": {
                    "MONDAY": {
                        "begin": "08:00",
                        "finish": "17:00"
                    },
                    "TUESDAY": {
                        "begin": "08:00",
                        "finish": "17:00"
                    },
                    "WEDNESDAY": {
                        "begin": "08:00",
                        "finish": "17:00"
                    },
                    "THURSDAY": {
                        "begin": "08:00",
                        "finish": "17:00"
                    },
                    "FRIDAY": {
                        "begin": "08:00",
                        "finish": "17:00"
                    }
                }
            },
}
 
 const checkWorkDay = () => {
    if (item?.work_schedule?.schedule) {
      const dayOnWork = Object.keys(item?.work_schedule?.schedule).filter(
        (el, index) => index == new Date().getDay() - 1
      ) // here I tried to filter one part of object I mean item. work_schedule.schedule

      let time = null

      switch (dayOnWork[0]) {
        case 'MONDAY': {
          time = item?.work_schedule?.schedule?.MONDAY
          break
        }
        case 'TUESDAY': {
          time = item?.work_schedule?.schedule?.TUESDAY
          break
        }
        case 'WEDNESDAY': {
          time = item?.work_schedule?.schedule?.WEDNESDAY
          break
        }
        case 'THURSDAY': {
          time = item?.work_schedule?.schedule?.THURSDAY
          break
        }
        case 'FRIDAY': {
          time = item?.work_schedule?.schedule?.FRIDAY
          break
        }
        case 'SATURDAY': {
          time = item?.work_schedule?.schedule?.SATURDAY
          break
        }
        case 'SUNDAY': {
          time = item?.work_schedule?.schedule?.SUNDAY
          break
        }
        default: {
          break
        }
      }
      let beginTime = time?.begin.split(':')
      let finishTime = time?.finish.split(':')

      if (beginTime !== null && finishTime !== null) {
        return (
          beginTime[0] <= new Date().getHours() &&
          finishTime[0] >= new Date().getHours()
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution of this issue**
*Firstly, we create array of weekdays in order to check today's weekday.
Secondly, we use func filter for making array and using destruction for gaining schedule.
Thirdly, we check whether in the array there is today's weekday if not then it returns false. Lastly, we convert again into array inside schedule weekday where begin and finish and split it and compare whether today's work hours are too early or it's time when it opened or it's closed*

```js
const filtByWeekOpened = (items) => {
    const days = [
      'SUNDAY',
      'MONDAY',
      'TUESDAY',
      'WEDNESDAY',
      'THURSDAY',
      'FRIDAY',
      'SATURDAY'
    ]

    const date = new Date()
    const today = days[date.getDay()]
    const time = date.getHours()

    return items.filter(({ work_schedule: { schedule } }, idx) => {
      if (!schedule.hasOwnProperty(today)) return false
      return (
        Number(schedule[today].begin.split(':')[0]) <=
        time <=
        Number(schedule[today].finish.split(':')[0])
      )
    })
  }
```

```html
  



  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```